How to get output weights in .tflite?
I have a tflite files, and then I want to output weights of last layer, How can I do ?
code
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="/content/drive/MyDrive/tflite_qaware_model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
interpreter.invoke()
print(output_details)

output
[{'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:0', 'index': 49, 'shape': array([ 1, 15], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([-1, 15], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]



Hi @TiWize ,If you want weight of last layer as your output you need to follow some more steps Here these are: ****Load the TFLite model.
****Allocate tensors.
****Identify the layer from which you want to extract weights.
****Access the weights directly if they are available in the model.
